# Showing a curve is not homotopic to a constant curve

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, homotopy-theory

[image]

This is an exercise from Conway. I managed to solve (a). But I can't explain in detail why the curve is not homotopic to zero (meaning homotopic to a constant curve). All I can intuitively see is that $\gamma$ is some kind of 'entangled' so it can't be reduced to a constant curve... Could anyone please explain in detail why this curve is not homotopic to zero?

Comment: The proof is rather intricate, and requires knowing a lot about fundamental groups and covering spaces. Has that been covered yet in your textbook? Do you know that material? If it's not in your textbook yet, I will guess that is why the exercise has "convince" and not "prove", and I will also guess that this material will occur at some later point in your textbook. I also guess that the author asked "Can you prove it?" because it's quite possible that a student reading that exercise does already know that material.

Comment: This is a direct analogue to the Boromean rings, if you are familiar with those.

Comment: This is a complex analysis book so there is no material on fundamental groups and covering spaces. I think the author just wants the reader to intuitively understand why this curve is not homotopic to zero. Could you just explain qualitatively? I think self-intersecting points are of problem.

Comment: @Keith It's not about self-intersecting points. You can easily construct self-intersecting loop contractible to a point (imagine that $a,b$ are "outside" of the loop, then it would be contractible even though it intersects itself). The important thing here is actually arrows which define winding. The $\mathbb{C}-\{a,b\}$ space is (homotopically equivalent to) wedge sum of two circles. Thus every path can be decomposed as a "free" combination of paths around $a$ and $b$ respectively.

Comment: Write $A, B$ for counterclockwise winding around $a, b$ respectively. Then the path is $AB^{-1}A^{-1}B$. But in order for that to be null-homotopic the $AB^{-1}A^{-1}B$ has to be reducable to the "empty word" which is impossible in the free group. Again this uses the fact that the fundamental group $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}-\{a, b\})$ is a free group on two generators $\mathbb{F}_2$

Comment: Also note that if you remove one of the points then (for example) $B$ becomes $A$ (there is only one winding now) and thus $AB^{-1}A^{-1}B=AA^{-1}A^{-1}A=e$ thus it is null-homotopic. All of that is an informal intuition.

Comment: By the way, there do exist complex analysis books that cover the topics of fundamental group and covering spaces.